# Perform a query on a sql database with Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm working on a python assignment and I am facing an issue. My question is the following:

"Write a query to select all rows from the `sales` table. Merge with the table returns by `INNER JOIN` on the `Order ID`. Put the result in a variable `QUERY`."

---

So I wrote this code:

```
sales_row = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM sales", mydb)
QUERY = pd.merge(sales_row, returns, on = "Order ID", how = "inner")
```

It works, but then I'm asked to perform a query on the database so I wrote the following:

```
pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, mydb)
```

And I get the following error:

> ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking you to write a query which selects all rows and merges it. so your query would be something like

```
query = "Select * from sales inner join returns on order id"
```

If you see the [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) documentation, you'll see the first argument must be a string, not a dataframe.

so after running the previous line I wrote, you can write

```
pd.read_sql_query(query, mydb)
```

where "query" is the string containing the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a misunderstanding. `pd.read_sql` and `pd.read_sql_query` are (roughly) the same thing. From the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) of `read_sql`: *This function is a convenience wrapper around read_sql_table and read_sql_query (for backward compatibility)*.

The output of `pd.read_sq` is a Pandas DataFrame. You don't explicit what `returns` is, but I guess it also is a DataFrame. So you could simply do

```py
sales_row = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM sales", mydb)
QUERY = sales_row.join(returns, on="Order ID", how="inner")
```

Note the use of `join` instead of `merge`.