# Automate a manual task using Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a question and hope someone can direct me in the right direction; Basically every week I have to run a query (SSMS) to get a table containing some information  (date, clientnumber, clientID, orderid etc) and then I copy all the information and that table and past it in a folder as a CSV file. it takes me about 15 min to do all this but I am just thinking can I automate this, if yes how can I do that and also can I schedule it so it can run by itself every week. I believe we live in a technological era and this should be done without human input; so I hope I can find someone here willing to show me how to do it using Python.

Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically scheduling SQL query results to be exported to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264116/automatically-scheduling-sql-query-results-to-be-exported-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Yes but I cannot find the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty simple to automate:

1. Use some database adapter which can work with your database, for MSSQL the one delivered by `pyodbc` will be fine,
2. Within the script, connect to the database, perform the query, parse an output,
3. Save parsed output to a `.csv` file (you can use `csv` Python module),
4. Run the script as the periodic task using `cron`/`schtask` if you work on Linux/Windows respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If you don't mind me asking how can I automate this file and send it to my colleague using Gmail

Comment: To send an email with an attachment using Python you can use `smtplib` https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your question is too broad, and shows no research effort.

You will find that Python can do the tasks you desire.

There are many different ways to [interact with SQL servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230753/perform-a-query-on-a-sql-database-with-python), depending on your implementation. I suggest you learn Python+SQL using the built-in `sqlite3` library. You will want to save your query as a string, and pass it into an SQL connection manager of your choice; this depends on your server setup, there are many different SQL packages for Python.

You can use `pandas` for parsing the data, and [saving it to a ~.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file) file (literally called `to_csv`).

Python does have many libraries for [scheduling tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), but I suggest you hold off for a while. Develop your code in a way that it can be run manually, which will still be much faster/easier than without Python. Once you know your code works, you can easily implement a scheduler. The downside is that your program will always need to be running, and you will need to keep checking to see if it is running. Personally, I would keep it restricted to manually running the script; you could compile to an ~.exe and bind to a hotkey if you need the accessibility.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment can you show me one way from the many diff ways, please? thank you

Comment: Please reference the hyperlinks that I have added to my answer. Since your question is vague, it is hard to provide information that is applicable to your exact situation. YouTube is also a great reference for the kinds of tasks you are trying to do. I suggest that you break up your problem into smaller problems, and research how to do each one. If you are only interested in getting a program that works, and not developing it yourself, you can contract me (or any other programmer) to develop for you.